# Apache CXF 3.16 soap client - premature end of file

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I am developing a SOAP client with Apache CXF 3.16. When I execute my client, the wildfly server respons with premature end of file. I needed to find out where this truncating has happend so I used fiddler and setup a proxy to catch the request, but then suddenly the error disappeared. Can Anyone explain what happens and I what I should do to solve this issue with CXF?

Regards

with fiddler:

```
ID: 1
```

Address: http://localhost:8080/iam/im/TEWS6/sbxd
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml

### Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["KMDCreateHRSoap"]}

---

ID: 1
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Headers: {connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[556], content-type=[text/xml;charset=utf-8], Date=[Tue, 07 Jun 2016 07:57:36 GMT], Server=[WildFly/8], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=jnbJb_S4XZDJp-mM8XqW513q.idmapp0002; path=/iam/im], X-Powered-By=[Undertow/1]}

Without Fiddler:

---

ID: 1
Address: http://localhost:8080/iam/im/TEWS6/sbxd
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["KMDCreateHRSoap"]}
Payload:

ID: 1
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Headers: {connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[983], content-type=[text/xml;charset=utf-8], Date=[Tue, 07 Jun 2016 08:03:50 GMT], Server=[WildFly/8], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=OnQoW3wBypZGI8qLWrjZ9lcs.idmapp0002; path=/iam/im], X-Powered-By=[Undertow/1]}

Comment: Is there a property I need to set for handling big soap requests with Apache cxf? It seems to work with smaller soap requests

Comment: Which stack is used on the server side? Also cxf?

Comment: yes cxf on serverside. Im not sure about version but I will find out. Good idea, maybe this version is old and with known bugs

Comment: found the vision apache cxf 2.7.13

Comment: I cant change the serverside version because its thirdparty component

Comment: I couldnt add the payload in here, if u know how let me know. thx

Comment: The content length of the requests differ between using fiddler and going straight forward `Content-Length=[556] != Content-Length=[983]` Perhaps you use a different encoding?

Comment: sorry, may be misleading. 556 is the length of response soap when using fiddler, but with fiddler the response soap goes well so it returns a soap that contains less elements than the reponse fails without fiddler which contains soap errorcode 500  description. But anyway it could have something to do with encoding, I will check up on that. Thx for replying

Comment: Could you add a CXF logging interceptor in server part to monitor the full soap mesaage in each case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this answer won't be to your taste, but your problem seems to be rooted in some security features of cxf. As a lot of attacks make use of large soap requests (extremly large element-names, content, and so on) there are certain restrictions what is allowed and what is not. You can find details for these restrictions on the [cxf-site](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/securing-cxf-services.html#SecuringCXFServices-ControllingLargeRequestPayloads).

Perhaps you can try to set the mentioned properties as System properties during wildfly-startup.

Comment: thx a lot for your respons :)  But why is it that large soap requests works if you go through fiddler? We had set the client up through fiddler listener port 8888 because we wanted to catch the large soap request and by doing that wildfly and cxf accepted it and it worked. why??

Comment: Can you look at the http headers received at the server with and without fiddler? And add a little more information what exactly is "big" in your request?

Comment: with fiddler:    POST /iam/im/TEWS6/sbxd HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

Accept: */*

SOAPAction: "KMDCreateHRSoap"

User-Agent: Apache CXF 3.1.6

Cache-Control: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Host: idmapp0002.idmdev.local:8080

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 4593

Comment: fyi: If you cut out the logged soap from cxf logger and run it through soapui it also works

Answer (score 0):

the reason was the soap request was chunked and even though I have set allowchunk to false, but it helped with autoredirect to false and setting soap protocol to 1.2 instead instead 1.1. thx for all the help!